# How to make an app use all cpu power available?

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

I'm in a 4-core machine with Intel processor, Windows 10.

I've made an example app forcing a loop , just to check the task manager and see what happens, something simple like this :

```
while true do begin end;
```

I'd expect the cpu will be at 100% with my process running at 100% too ; this was what happened back then when processors have only one core.

But this is not what happens now, my app never uses more then 25% of total CPU power, as shown on task manager. Because it's a 4-core machine, i'm wondering if it's using only one core at full capacity.

Is this 'issue' due the fact i'm running only one thread ?

What should i make to my app really take advantage of all processing power available ?

Comment: Yes. If you have *N* virtual processors, you need *N* busy threads to use all your CPU power. For instance, I have a 4-core HT processor, so for me N = 8. You seem to have a 4-core CPU without HT, so your N = 4.

Comment: By the way, why do you write `while True do begin end;` when a simple `while True do;` suffices?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Thanks ! To be honest, i did not know i don't need to use begin end on this case.

Comment: You can use [`TThread.ProcessorCount`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.ProcessorCount) to know how many threads you should create.

Comment: @RemyLebeau ...for an [embarrassingly parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel) problem, yes, but depending on the algorithm it can be advantageous to use a number of working threads that is different from the number of logical CPU cores available.  I don't think there's a one-size-fits-all answer to the number of threads one *should* create for any given problem.  Related (albeit with some outdated answers) : [Optimal number of threads per core](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1718465/327083)

Comment: Related : [Simple Thread Sample Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3451138/327083)

Comment: Probably also helpful : [Advice for converting a large monolithic singlethreaded application to a multithreaded architecture?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2204216/327083)

Comment: And : [Achieving Thread-Safety](https://stackoverflow.com/q/564319/327083), because it will become a problem quickly once you start down this road.

Comment: Also, the documentation is a good place to start : [Parallel Programming Library Tutorials](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Parallel_Programming_Library_Tutorials)

Comment: [Defining thread objects](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Defining_thread_objects_Index)

Comment: "*I've made an example app forcing a loop , just to check the task manager and see what happens*" - You can do some pretty tricky stuff with Task Manager using careful crafted CPU loads: https://youtu.be/hSoCmAoIMOU

Comment: @RemyLebeau That's... horrifying, lol.

Comment: @RemyLebeau This is probably the nerdiest thing i saw in all my entire life ! lol